# How to use GDB to check where a function calls return?

Tags: function, debugging, testing, return, gdb

I have a function called test_linked_list() that tests a data structure using a series of if statements. If a test fails it calls return 0.

```
// ie.
test_linked_list() {
    if(!insert_end(l,10)) 
        return 0;
    // ... more tests
}
```

I want to know which test fails. Instead of setting breakpoints manually in gdb and using `next` to see which `return 0` is called, is there another way? For example, a GDB script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there another way?

One simple way to use the UNIX convention of `return 0` on success, and `return 1`, `return 2`, etc. for different failures.

Note that compilers ~always use a *single* `return` for each function; there aren't "which return" -- they are all the same once the function is compiled.